# I have a mysterious mistake on game maker

Tags: compiler-errors, game-maker

I have a mistake in my code

this program should allow me to move my character

my mistake:

```
___________________________________________
COMPILATION ERROR in Script: player_movement
Error in code at line 11:
   var moveH = key_right - key_left;
             ^
at position 12: Unexpected symbol in expression.
```

I did research on the internet but I did not find anything

```
// recuper touche des clavier
key_left = keyboard_check(vk_left);
key_right = keyboard_check(vk_right);
key_up = keyboard_check(vk_up);
key_down = keyboard_check(vk_down);



// mouvements du joueur

var moveH = key_right - key_left;

hsp = moveH * movesp;

var moveV = key_down - key_up;

vsp = moveV * movesp;

if (key_up && !place_meeting(x, y - 2, object_collision)) || (key_down && !place_meeting(x, y + 2, object_collision))
{
y += vsp;


} else if (key_right  && !place_meeting(x + 2, y, object_collision))|| (key_left && !place_meeting(x - 2, y, object_collision ))
{
 x += hsp;

}

//animation du joueur

if (hsp == 0) && (vsp == 0)
{
image_index = 0;
  image_speed = 0;
} else 
{
  image_speed = 1;
}


if key_right
{
 sprite_index = persoDroite;
} else if key_left
{
 sprite_index = persoGauche;
}else if key_up
{
 sprite_index = persoArriere;
}else if key_down
{
 sprite_index = persoFace;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GameMaker 8, you cannot do `var name = value`, it has to be `var name; name = value` (or otherwise declaring the variable prior to assigning), so that line would have to be

```
var moveH; moveH = key_right - key_left;
```

(you can also group declarations together like `var moveH, moveV;`)